# How do I make these animation work with this if else if else statement

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

### My Jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ( $("a#k").data('clicked'))
  {
    $("#contentfour").hide();
    $("#contact").hide();
      function() {
     $("#contentthree").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
      },
        function() {
     $("#contentthree").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);

       }
  }
    else if  ( $("a#o").data('clicked'))
  {
    $("#contact").hide();
    $("#contentthree").hide();
       function() {
      $("#contentfour")show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
      },
        function() {
      $("#contentfour").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);

       }

  }
    else( $("a#toggle").data('clicked'))
  {
    $("#contentfour").hide();
    $("#contentthree").hide();
    $(function ()
    {
      $("a#toggle").click(function()
      {
        $("#contact").slideToggle();
        return false;
       }); 
   });

  });
  });
```

---

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.responsive.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="klogic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

</head>
<body>

  <div id="full-size">
    <div id="one">
      <div id="kt"><!--one -->
        <h3><a href="#" id="toggle">Contact</a></h3>
        <h3><a href="#"id="k">Portfolio</a></h3>
        <h3><a href="#"id="o">Blog</a></h3>
        <img src="logo.png" style="width:110px;height:110px;"/>
      </div><!-- taking out one -->
    </div>

    <div id="two"><div id="contact" >kflskf;sdkfdskfldsfks</div></div><!--red-->
      <div id="three"><div id="contentthree">gdfgdsfgsd</div></div><!--green-->
        <div id="four"><div id="contentfour" >gsdfgdsgdsfg</div></div><!--blue-->
     </div>

  </body>
<html>
```

---

### my css code:

```
html, body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}

#full-size {
  background-image:url(bg.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;  
}

#one
{
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  background-color:orange;
  float:left;
  opacity:0.80;
  filter:alpha(opacity=80);
}
#two
{
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  background-color:red;
  float:left;
  opacity:0.60;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
#three
{
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  background-color:green;
  float:left;
  opacity:0.60;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
#four
{
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  background-color:blue;
  float:left;
  opacity:0.60;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
#kt
{
  width:200px;
  height:175px;
  background-color:grey;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  left:200px;
  top:-10px;  
}
#contact
{
/*width:623.5px;
  height:285px;*/
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: grey;
  float:left;
  display:none; 
}
#contentthree
{
  /*width:623.5px;
  height:290px;*/
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:grey;
  float:right;
  display: none;   
}

#contentfour
{
  /*width:623.5px;
  height:290px;*/
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display: none;
  background-color:red;
  float:right;
}
#k { width: 500px; height: 200px; background-color: green; border: 1px solid black; position: relative; font-size:175%;}
#o { width: 500px; height: 200px; background-color: blue; border: 1px solid black; position: relative; font-size:175%;}
#toggle { width: 500px; height: 200px; background-color: yellow; border: 1px solid black; position: relative;font-size:175%; }
```

---

My main problem is with my jquery/Javascript im trying to create a logic for my three animations that work , i want them to load one at the time , so when one loaded the other 2 hide.
Thanks.

Comment: Too much stuff here including sourced javascript on your server that we cannot see. Narrow the question down to the actual issue, creating a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) will also help.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need to put any `if` or `else if` for things to work.**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/mNeL4/)**

```
 $(function() {
     $("a#k").click(function(){
          $("#contentfour").hide();
    $("#contact").hide();

     $("#contentthree").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);


     $("#contentthree").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);

     });  


  $("a#o").click(function(){

    $("#contact").hide();
    $("#contentthree").hide();

      $("#contentfour").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);


      $("#contentfour").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);


  });

  $("a#toggle").click(function(){

    $("#contentfour").hide();
    $("#contentthree").hide();

        $("#contact").slideToggle();

   });

});
```